# Name node is down due to QJM, Unable to check if JNs are ready for formatting

Tags: hadoop

Tried to manually format the namenode getting the below error,

sudo hdfs namenode -format

```
User: $K25000-OITV3IAVUNTB@XXXX.COM is not allowed to impersonate nn/xxxx-0xx0xx084.xxxx.com@XXXX.COM
```

Any one have an idea about the below exception in ambari-metrics-collector.log
your input is much appreciated.

please find the logs for reference,

```
20/03/26 08:56:29 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Using INode attribute provider: org.apache.ranger.authorization.hadoop.RangerHdfsAuthorizer
20/03/26 08:56:29 WARN namenode.NameNode: Encountered exception during format:
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.qjournal.client.QuorumException: Unable to check if JNs are ready for formatting. 1 exceptions thrown:
10.xx.xx.xx:8485: User: $K25000-OITV3IAVUNTB@XXXX.COM is not allowed to impersonate nn/xxxx-0xx0xx084.xxxx.com@XXXX.COM
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.qjournal.client.QuorumException.create(QuorumException.java:81)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.qjournal.client.QuorumCall.rethrowException(QuorumCall.java:286)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.qjournal.client.QuorumJournalManager.hasSomeData(QuorumJournalManager.java:253)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage.confirmFormat(Storage.java:1142)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.confirmFormat(FSImage.java:196)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:1155)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1xx0)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1710)
20/03/26 08:56:29 ERROR namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.qjournal.client.QuorumException: Unable to check if JNs are ready for formatting. 1 exceptions thrown:
10.xx.xx.xx:8485: User: $K25000-OITV3IAVUNTB@XXXX.COM is not allowed to impersonate nn/xxxx
0xx0xx084.xxxx.com@XXXX.COM
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.qjournal.client.QuorumException.create(QuorumException.java:81)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.qjournal.client.QuorumCall.rethrowException(QuorumCall.java:286)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.qjournal.client.QuorumJournalManager.hasSomeData(QuorumJournalManager.java:253)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage.confirmFormat(Storage.java:1142)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.confirmFormat(FSImage.java:196)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:1155)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1xx0)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1710)
20/03/26 08:56:29 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1:
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.qjournal.client.QuorumException: Unable to check if JNs are ready for formatting. 1 exceptions thrown:
10.xx.xx.xx:8485: User: $K25000-OITV3IAVUNTB@XXXX.COM is not allowed to impersonate nn/xxxx-0xx0xx084.xxxx.com@XXXX.COM
20/03/26 08:56:29 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at xxxx-0xx0000xx.xxxx.com/10.00.xx.xx
```